# How to sum u32 with dynamic int that can take negative values?

Tags: rust, sum, integer, conways-game-of-life

I'm new to Rust, please help me.

I'm going through [Rust and WebAssembly](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/introduction.html) book. In chapter «Adding Interactivity» there is some [exercises](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/interactivity.html#exercises). One of them is to insert a [pulsar](https://playgameoflife.com/lexicon/pulsar) by clicking on cell with pressed Shift key. For inserting pulsar I created this function:

```rust
pub fn insert_pulsar(&mut self, row: u32, column: u32) {
        fn get_pulsar_sector(row: u32, column: u32, x: i32, y: i32) -> Vec<(u32, u32)> {
            let vec = vec![
                (row + (1 * y), column + (2 * x)), 
                (row + (1 * y), column + (3 * x)), 
                (row + (1 * y), column + (4 * x)), 
                (row + (6 * y), column + (2 * x)),  
                (row + (6 * y), column + (3 * x)),  
                (row + (6 * y), column + (4 * x)),  
                (row + (2 * y), column + (1 * x)), 
                (row + (3 * y), column + (1 * x)), 
                (row + (4 * y), column + (1 * x)),
                (row + (2 * y), column + (6 * x)),  
                (row + (3 * y), column + (6 * x)),  
                (row + (4 * y), column + (6 * x)),  
            ];

            vec
        }

        let top_left_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, -1, -1);
        let top_right_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, 1, -1);
        let bottom_right_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, 1, 1);
        let bottom_right_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, -1, 1);

        let pulsar = [
            top_left_pulsar_sector, 
            top_right_pulsar_sector, 
            bottom_right_pulsar_sector, 
            bottom_right_pulsar_sector
        ].concat();

        self.set_cells(&pulsar);
    }
```

But when I'm trying to compile my project I get errors like this:

```sh
error[E0277]: cannot add `i32` to `u32`
   --> src/lib.rs:197:40
    |
197 |                 (row + (4 * y), column + (6 * x)),  
    |                                        ^ no implementation for `u32 + i32`
    |
    = help: the trait `Add<i32>` is not implemented for `u32`
```

As you can see, x and y is used to set position for pulsar's sector. What can I do to `get_pulsar_sector` function code to make this work?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/cast.html

Comment: @Maskliin, Wow, i thought you cant just covert negative value to unsigned integer with `as`. How does this work?

Comment: You can absolutely cast negative values to unsigned with `as`, though obviously the relevant consequences will apply (namely two-complement overflow). Alternatively you can use `TryFrom`/`TryInto` to perform a conversion with notification of overflow. Here you're converting from u32 to i32 though, so it's not really a factor, though you will get an overflow (with the usual consequences) if the values are higher than 2^31-1.

Comment: Thank you @Masklinn!

Answer (score 0):

You can [cast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/cast.html) negative values to unsigned with `as`. In my case I did:

```rust
pub fn insert_pulsar(&mut self, row: u32, column: u32) {
    fn get_pulsar_sector(row: u32, column: u32, x: isize, y: isize) -> Vec<(u32, u32)> {
        let vec = vec![
            (row + (1 * y) as u32, column + (2 * x) as u32), 
            (row + (1 * y) as u32, column + (3 * x) as u32), 
            (row + (1 * y) as u32, column + (4 * x) as u32), 
            (row + (6 * y) as u32, column + (2 * x) as u32),  
            (row + (6 * y) as u32, column + (3 * x) as u32),  
            (row + (6 * y) as u32, column + (4 * x) as u32),  
            (row + (2 * y) as u32, column + (1 * x) as u32), 
            (row + (3 * y) as u32, column + (1 * x) as u32), 
            (row + (4 * y) as u32, column + (1 * x) as u32),
            (row + (2 * y) as u32, column + (6 * x) as u32),  
            (row + (3 * y) as u32, column + (6 * x) as u32),  
            (row + (4 * y) as u32, column + (6 * x) as u32),  
        ];

        vec
    }

    let top_left_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, -1, -1);
    let top_right_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, 1, -1);
    let bottom_right_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, 1, 1);
    let bottom_left_pulsar_sector = get_pulsar_sector(row, column, -1, 1);

    let pulsar = [
        &top_left_pulsar_sector[..], 
        &top_right_pulsar_sector[..], 
        &bottom_right_pulsar_sector[..], 
        &bottom_left_pulsar_sector[..],
    ].concat();

    self.set_cells(&pulsar);
}
```

And it compiled.

Thanks to @Masklinn!